# pyinstaller "could not parse stylesheet"

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I'm building a small program using pyQt and pyInstaller.
I've tried to add an background image to my QMainWindow:

```
class pyPrimaMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...do some stuff...
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(os.path.join(self.py_prima.resource_path(), "TH.ico"))) # <- this works
        self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{{border-image: url({0});background-size:100%;}}".format(os.path.join(self.py_prima.resource_path(), "bg.png")))
```

The resource_path() methods looks like that:

```
def resource_path(self):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
    base_path = getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', "C:/Users/Tobias/eclipse/workspace/PyPrima/data/")
    #         except Exception:
    #             base_path =

    print(base_path)
    return base_path
```

It's copied from the pyinstaller wiki, returns an absoulte path and works for other pictures/icons.
However, if I build an executable with pyInstaller, the programm runs nice, but the background image is missing. Instead, the console outputs

```
"could not parse stylesheet of object ..."
```

If I run the python file, it works all fine...

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own question just in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem.

The fileseparators are wrong...
Fix it with

```
bgpath = os.path.join(self.py_prima.resource_path(), "bg.png")
bgpath = bgpath.replace("\\", "/")
self.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{{border-image: url({0});background-size: 100%;}}".format(
        bgpath))
```